# Drawing Shapes with lines on a transparent Graphics2D to get a png image

Tags: java, swing, background, bufferedimage, graphics2d

So my goal is to have a window that opens where you can draw some lines on a white background by just clicking. The problem is that when it try to save it always comes back as a png, but it comes as a square image. If I draw a triangle with my lines I get a triangle inside a white square but I want the triangle only. I would really appreciate any help

I tried every solution I came accross on stackoverflow and I tried to understand Graphics2D in depth but sadly failed

```
    public class Draw{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Icon iconB = new ImageIcon("blue.gif");
        Icon iconM = new ImageIcon("magenta.gif");
        Icon iconR = new ImageIcon("red.gif");
        Icon iconBl = new ImageIcon("black.gif");
        Icon iconG = new ImageIcon("green.gif");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Paint It");
        //Creates a frame with a title of "Paint it"

        Container content = frame.getContentPane();
        //Creates a new container
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //sets the layout

        final PadDraw drawPad = new PadDraw();
        //creates a new padDraw, which is pretty much the paint program

        content.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //sets the padDraw in the center

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setOpaque(false);
        //creates a JPanel
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(32, 68));
        panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(32, 68));
        panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(32, 68));
        //This sets the size of the 

        content.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //sets the panel to the left

        frame.setSize(480, 360);
        //sets the size of the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //makes it so you can close
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //makes it so you can see it
    }
}

class PadDraw extends JComponent{
Image image;
//this is gonna be your image that you draw on
Graphics2D graphics2D;
//this is what we'll be using to draw on
int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;
//these are gonna hold our mouse coordinates
int firstX;
int firstY;

//Now for the constructors
//will draw from tail to head
public PadDraw(){
    setDoubleBuffered(false);
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            if (currentX == 0 && currentY == 0) {
                firstX= e.getX();
                firstY = e.getY();
                oldX = e.getX();
                oldY = e.getY();
            }
            currentX = e.getX();
            currentY = e.getY();
            graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
            repaint();
            oldX = currentX;
            oldY = currentY;
        }
    });
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    if(image == null){
        image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
        graphics2D = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphics2D.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
        graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        graphics2D.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
        clear();
    }
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
//this is the painting bit
//if it has nothing on it then
//it creates an image the size of the window
//sets the value of Graphics as the image
//sets the rendering
//runs the clear() method
//then it draws the image

public void clear(){
    currentX = 0;
    currentY = 0;

    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.white);
    graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.black);
    repaint();
}
//this is the clear
//it sets the colors as white
//then it fills the window with white
//thin it sets the color back to black

public void save(){
    repaint();
    if (currentX != 0 && currentY != 0) {
        graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, firstX, firstY);
        currentX = 0;
        currentY = 0;
    }

    try {
        BufferedImage bfrdImage = new BufferedImage
    (image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        // Draw the image on to the buffered image
        Graphics2D bGr = bfrdImage.createGraphics();

        bGr.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
        bGr.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        bGr.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
        bGr.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

        javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(bfrdImage, "PNG", new File("Drawing.PNG"));
        bGr.dispose();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PadDraw.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
//saves and also comes back to the first point to finalize the shape}
```

Comment: You should not be using a graphics context outside of paintComponentif you are painting on the screen. Please check this Java Tutorials segment on Custom Painting. Anytime you need to update something that is to be painted, the appropriate values should be set and then a repaint() should be called.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```java
    public class PaintDemo extends JPanel {

       JFrame frame = new JFrame();

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new PaintDemo());
       }

       public PaintDemo() {
          setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.add(this);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          setBackground(Color.white);
          frame.setVisible(true);
       }

       public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
          g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
          g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
          g2d.fillOval(200, 200, 100, 100);

          // triangle
          g2d.setColor(Color.red);
          g2d.drawLine(100, 200, 200, 100);
          g2d.drawLine(200, 100, 300, 400);
          g2d.drawLine(300, 400, 100, 200);

          g2d.setColor(Color.magenta);
          g2d.fillRect(100, 100, 200, 50);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I'm still struggling with the white square png problem. Do you have any idea how i could fix it as well? I have been struggling with it all day :(

Comment: There's also more to the code that I edited in if it can help find an answer